# Android Studio Auto Suggestion list get blank

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio version 3.0 Canary 5.0. While it work most of time and stable enough but sometime it automatic blank suggestion pop-up window window e.g. Class Suggestion.

Any suggestion how to fix this, I have to restart IDE every-time to fix it.

[image]

Comment: atm, Canary is at 8, try again.